# Define EOF character

Tags: c, posix

Out of curiosity is it possible to temporarily add a character that should be interpreted as EOF? For example using the read() syscall in a loop, and have it abort on `'\n'` by register the new line character as EOF temporarily.

Comment: See also: http://www.glue.umd.edu/afs/glue.umd.edu/system/info/olh/Programming/C_Programming_on_Glue/The_Third_C_Program_Character_Data/eof_stdio

Comment: Any arbitrary character, or just newline?

Comment: @CarlNorum In this case the newline, but out of curiosity any arbitrary character. If you happen to know a special case for `\n` do tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, not possible. If you want to read from a file descriptor until you encounter a specific character, and avoid reading anything past it (so as not to consume input needed later by another process, for instance) the only solution is to perform 1-byte reads. It's slow but that's how it is.

Comment: Use stdio (or the C++ equivalent) buffering instead - saves on the system calls and you can check the next character is the one you are looking for. You can configure it to read a chunk of data from disk.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I suspected. I had this thought, "gee I wonder if.." and wanted to check with the Stack overflow community.

Comment: @EdHeal: Indeed, this is what you should do if you're the only one reading from a file descriptor, but it won't help if you want to share the fd with other processes. For instance, if you want to implement something like the shell `read` command (where subsequent input remains on the fd for the next command to read), or if you're implementing a webserver and want it to pass off the body of the request (e.g. POST) to a child process after processing the header.

Answer (score 3):

Not easily, but it's possible that you could do something with [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fdopen.html) and a custom function:

```
int freadtochar(char *buffer, int size, char character, FILE *filePtr)
{
    int index = 0;
    char c;
    while (index < size && (c = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF && c != character)
    {
        buffer[index++] = c; 
    }

    return index;
} 

int main()
{
    int fd = STDIN_FILENO;

    FILE *filePtr = fdopen(dup(fd), "r");

    char buffer[1024];
    int bytesRead = freadtochar(buffer, 1024, '\n', filePtr);

    // buffer should now contain all characters up to '\n', but note no trailing '\0' is added
    fclose(filePtr);
}
```

Note that this still reads from the original file descriptor, it just buffers the data for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will resort to something like this.

Comment: Note that this still pulls the data off the fd; it just does the buffering for you. Also note that `fclose` closes the original fd, so if you don't want that, you should `fdopen(dup(fd), "r");` instead.