# Redefine EOF as character string

Tags: c++, eof, istream-iterator

I'm trying to write a program that gets a sequence of words, put them into a vector and then does things with them. I've found one way that works, which is:

```
{
    vector<string> inputs;
    string Input;
    cin >> Input;
    while (Input != "Quit") 
    {
        inputs.push_back(Input);
        cin >> Input;
    }
}
```

However I'm trying to use another method to do it, which is:

```
{
    istream_iterator<string> ii(cin);
    istream_iterator<string> eos;
    vector<string> inputs(ii, eos);
}
```

But I have no idea how to make `Quit` mean EOF, which would end the input stream and put the words into the vector. How do I make the string `"Quit"` act as a stream terminator?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827367/define-eof-character

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710604/how-do-i-set-eof-on-an-istream-without-reading-formatted-input

Comment: I'm a complete novice so the answers cited above seem to me to be pretty vague. Pardon.

Answer (score 1):

`EOF` is defined as `-1` in `cstdio`. You could try `#undef EOF` and `#define EOF "Quit"`, but this will probably break implementations that rely on `EOF` being a signed integer and/or `-1`. So basically, leave it alone.

Comment: So might there be any other way other than trying to make `"Quit"` act as `EOF`?